# Module to easily insert link to other content into textarea?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Title pretty much says it all. I want a button or something next to the textarea that will let you link selected text to a particular node.

I am guessing that I should be using the WYSIWYG module with a particular editor, and happy to hear suggestions as to which combination.

Answer (score 2):

[CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) with [CKEditor Link](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link) does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for that. Only problem is CKEditor. I think I will write my own module that works for plain textareas.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not a button, but node_link creates links to a given node number.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for as I want it to be as painless as possible for the end user, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about Linkit?

"Linkit provides an easy interface for internal and external linking with editors and fields by using an autocomplete field. Linkit links to nodes, users, managed files, terms and have basic support for all entities by default.
Linkit has three major advantages over traditional linking"

https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit